# Angular 8+, make component factories in lazy module available in global service

Tags: angular, dialog, factory

I have written a ModalService to wrap both MatDialog and MatSnackBar, to avoid injecting both in each of my components, and this service offers methods that wrap the material ones. So you can write

```
modalService.dialog(MyDialogComponent, { data: {} });
```

instead of

```
matDialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { data: {} });
```

ModalService is declared in ModalModule, and provided in its forRoot method, so in my AppModule I import it:

ModalModule.ts:

```
@NgModule({ imports: [MatDialogModule, ...], ... })
public class ModalModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return { ngModule: ModalModule, providers: [{ provide: ModalService, useClass: ModalService }] };
    }
}
```

AppModule.ts:

```
@NgModule({ imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(), ...], ... })
public class AppModule {}
```

I have other modules, some of which are lazily loaded, which import the ModalModule and declare some entry components to open in a dialog:
LazyModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [MatDialogModule, ModalModule, ...], // <--- ModalModule without forRoot()
    declarations: [MyDialogComponent, MyLazyComponent],
    entryComponents: [MyDialogComponent],
})
public class LazyModule {}
```

Now, if in MyLazyComponent I try to use ModalService to open MyDialogComponent, I get an error saying that no factory has been found for MyDialogComponent, whereas when using dialog.open, it works as expected.

MyLazyComponent:

```
modalService.dialog(MyDialogComponent); // <--- error
matDialog.open(MyDialogComponent); // <--- fine
```

While debugging with dev tools I noticed that somewhere inside the code of MatDialog, matDialog has a reference to the injector of the LazyModule, which has a ComponentFactoryResolver which correctly contains the factory for MyDialogComponent, whereas ModalService has a reference to the AppModule's injector, which doesn't contain those factories.
I understand the reason why: I've provided the service in the AppModule and not in the LazyModule. What I'm not getting is how to fix this, or why does MatDialog have a reference to the injector of the LazyModule.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#prevent-reimport-of-the-greetingmodule

Comment: Why do you want to have imported as ``forRoot()`` in your app module? You are importing it at every module afterwards, do you have any data in that service you want to share across all the application?

Comment: @Gonzalo indeed I ended up importing it in every module because after all my ModalService doesn't share any "singleton" data, unlike for example an AuthService with a BehaviorSubject holding info on the logged user.
Material's DialogModule does provide the service in the NgModule metadata too, instead of providing it in a forRoot method, so MatDialog is instantiated in every lazy module that imports it and this is why it has access to the lazy module's NgFactories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments to my question, MatDialog is provided in MatDialogModule's decorator, therefore for each lazy module a new instance of the MatDialog is created, with visibility on that module's components. After all, a dialog service doesn't need to be a singleton and this approach is fine, so I've ended up providing my modal service in the module's metadata too instead of just in the forRoot method.